# Use `arch -x86_64` on terminal in vscode on macos

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm new to mac and looking for pain relief.

I have a dependency that doesn't run on apple silicon. Meaning: if I `cd` into the project folder and run `poetry install`, I get an error message:

[image]

I'm able to remedy this by starting the terminal in "intel" aka "rosetta mode" using `arch -x86_64 alacritty`. Then, the dependencies install just fine.

#### So-far, so good.

However, **I use VS-Code for development, and I cannot get to use the same settings in the integrated terminal there.** The default profile has the same problem described above.

#### What I've tried

I tried adding a terminal profile in `settings.json`...

[image]

...but that appears to be incorrect. I cannot use `"bash_2"` as the value for `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx"`, and `bash_2` is also not shown in the list of terminals:

[image]

I also tried starting vscode entirely with rosetta, but the app is compiled for apple silicon only. Plus, I doubt this would solve the issue - if vscode spawns a terminal, it might not automatically use rosetta as well.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider porting from pyqt5 to pyside6 for official Apple Silicon support? PySide6 is the official python bindings for Qt6. PyQT6 is also an option with slightly more similar syntax to PyQT5, though it lacks some things like pyrcc for working with `.qrc` files.

Also, VSCode offers both an arm64 build (119 MB) and a universal build (202 MB).

But to answer the question, add this to the user `settings.json`:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "x86 zsh": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/arch",
            "args": ["-arch", "x86_64", "/bin/zsh"]
        }
    },
```

Based on the answer here, which I confirmed works for me. (This was the first google result for "vscode rosetta". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217885/configure-m1-vscode-arm-but-with-a-rosetta-terminal

Update: if you specifically need bash, you'll either need to find a universal version of bash or install the Rosetta version of brew to get Rosetta bash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My reactions, in order: (1) I cannot upgrade to pyqt6, as it's a dependency of a dependency. I didn't state this in my question though. (2) I did install vscode in both versions, but starting the intel version does nothing as the issue is the terminal in which code is run, which it turns out is separate. (3) That works! ...

Comment: ...however, when I replace `/bin/zsh` with `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`, it doesn't. Any suggestions on how to use bash here, as it's the shell I always use?

Comment: In my experience, brew only installs the native version of things. For example, brew installing python only installs the arm64 version. I need to download from python.org to get the universal version. You'll need to find a universal version of bash. Or run brew through Rosetta to get the Rosetta bash.

Comment: Also note that Rosetta brew installs things in a different location so Rosetta bash shouldn't coflict your existing install of native bash.

Comment: Wait, can’t you just use Rosetta Python in normal bash? Install universal Python from Python.org

Comment: I guess I'm most confused about the chain of dependencies. If I start bash in rosetta mode, and then run `python` or `pip`, do they automatically run in rosetta mode too? And the packages installed using pip? (I don't have to run the entire OS in rosetta mode, so non-rosetta apps can run rosetta apps and vice versa) How about virtual environments that I create while running bash/python/poetry/pip in rosetta mode, do they retain rosetta mode when activating them at some point in the future?